# How to programatically add a bean to webApplicationContext in junit test?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am trying to write a unit test to test a filter in junit.  The filter in question has an `init` method which takes the `filterConfig` object, uses it to get the `WebApplicationContext`, and then calls `getBeanAs` on that context to find properties it needs to filter.

My unit test currently has a `webApplicationContext` autowired using `@WebAppConfiguration` which I can plug into a `MockFilterConfig` and pass to the `init` method, so far so good.

The problem is that in our actual application the properties loaded from the `WebApplicationContext` are ultimately read from mongo using a propertyConfigurer.  I obviously don't want to load things from mongo for the tests, so I removed the propertyConfigurer from the applicationContext I'm using when I generate the webApplicationContext.

I could manually add each property to the applicationContext, except I'd like to be able to change the properties the filter is initialized to for various tests.

So is there a way I can programmatically add these beans to the webApplicationContext after it's autowired, so I can change what the filter initializes to based off of the test I'm writing?

I'm not committed to generating the `WebApplicationContext` via the `@webAppConfiguration` annotation, but I wasn't able to find a good way of generating a mock other then manually which felt too brittle, as I would have to make so many presumptions about the inner working of webApplicaitoncontext.

Comment: Maybe use a Spring Profile to include different beans depending on the environment?